# F#- How can we validate the whole schema of API response using HttpFs.Client or Hopac?

Tags: f#, httpfs

I have a test where after getting a response I would like to validate the entire schema of the response (not individual response node/value comparison).

Sample test:

```
    [<Test>]         
let howtoValidateSchema () =             
    let request = Request.createUrl Post "https://reqres.in/api/users"                        
               |> Request.setHeader (Accept "application/json")                        
               |> Request.bodyString """{"name": "morpheus",          "job": "leader"}"""          
               |> Request.responseAsString                        
               |> run
```

Is there a way that I can save my expected Schema somewhere and once I get the response I do the comparison to check that response has same number of nodes (neither less nor more than expected schema)?

I am ok to opt for other libs like FSharp.Data if we there is no direct way in HttpFs.Client. I looked at FSharp.Data (https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html) but not able to seek how it meets the requirements where the schema comparison needs to be done with the savedExpectedSchemaJson=ResponseJson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Newtonsoft.Json.Schema`to validate schemas:

```
open Newtonsoft.Json.Schema
open Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

let schema = JSchema.Parse expectedSchema
let json = JObject.Parse responeJson
let valid = json.IsValid schema
```

However this assumes you have a schema predefined somewhere. If you don't have such schema is best to use the JsonProvider who can infer it for you.

Run the call manually and save the result in a *sample.json* file and create a type using the JsonProvider:

```
type ResponseSchema = JsonProvider<"sample.json">
```

and you can use this type to parse any new content based on the sample (provided that the sample is a representative.

```
ResponseSchema.parse response
```

This won't validate the schema but will try to meet as best as it can given the input.

Comment: I have schema pre-defined so this worked pretty well. Thanks.